# How to make dialog look same in all versions from 2.2 to 4.4 and also in all tablets

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

How to make dialog look same in all versions from 2.2 to 4.4 and also in all tablets.i had created dialog which look perfect in 4.2 and i want same dialog to look in 2.3 also.How to make dialog look same in all versions from 2.2 to 4.4 and also in all tablets.i had created dialog which look perfect in 4.2 and i want same dialog to look in 2.3 also.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private Context context;
private TextView textView;
private Dialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = MainActivity.this;
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            MainActivity.this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    alertDialog.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_textview, null));



    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Call",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    // Write your code here to invoke YES event
                    if (deviceIsTablet(context)) { // if device is a
                        // tablet
                        if (isAppInstalled("com.skype.raider")) {
                            // insert what you want to do if device has
                            // skype
                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    "android.intent.action.VIEW");
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + 123456789));
                            startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            // connect to Play store or whatever
                            startActivity(new Intent(
                                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                    Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skype.raider")));
                        }
                    } else { // if device is not a tablet
                        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
                        startActivity(callIntent);
                    }
                }
            });

    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Write your code here to invoke NO event

                }
            });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();

}

// determine whether or no the android device is a tablet or not
public static boolean deviceIsTablet(Context c) {
    Resources res = c.getResources();
    return (res.getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}

private boolean isAppInstalled(String appToCheck) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean isOnDevice = false;
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(appToCheck, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        isOnDevice = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException exception) {
        isOnDevice = false;
    }
    return isOnDevice;
}
```

}

Comment: You need to create custom dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Check below links to create custom dialog :

- [Custom Dialog 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)
- [Custom Dialog 2](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/)
- [Custom Dialog 3](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/dialog/android-custom-dialog-example/)
- [Custom Dialog 4](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Dialog_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=88&aaid=111)

Steps to create custom dialog :

- Create a layout file (eg dialog.xml)
- Reference your dialog.xml class with your activity.
- Bundle the new layout file with the View of the Dialog Box.
- Display the dialog.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. Post links as commen or elaborate your answer